# SQL Server CE4 Update with select

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-ce, sql-update, sql

I have the following SQL targeting SQL Server 2008:

```
declare @id bigint;

update [dbo].[Identities] 
set @id = CurrentId + 1, CurrentId = CurrentId + @numOfIds 
where [EntityHash] = @entityHash;

select @id as StructureId;
```

I need the same semantics for SQLCE4. Tried to have @id as an output parameters, and then used:

```
update [Identities] 
set @id = CurrentId + 1, CurrentId = CurrentId + @numOfIds 
where [EntityHash] = @entityHash;
```

but as it turned out, output parameters are not supported in SQL Server CE 4.

Comment: You will have to use multiple statements

Comment: and to ensure that I read back the value consistent with the update statement, without having a transaction in ADO.Net? BTW, thanks for great SQLCE projects on CodePlex.